# I am trying to get Product Image on Shopping cart , in magento Admin

Tags: product-images

[image: I am trying to get Product Image on Shopping cart , in magneto admin panel. i have checked below path: /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml]
[[image]][1 pl check attached snapshot,

Answer (score 1):

I use this 
[module](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-grids-editor.html)

I never tried it on customers menu but it should work.

Give it a try on a dev enviroment.

Comment: I vouch for this module. It does what is requested and more. I'm not a fanboy, I just don't see the point in reinventing the wheel :)

Comment: I am a fanboy to anything that is simple and does what it says. :P